# Two markings at one line with decorations in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, decorations

I would like to draw a path with an arrowtip at the beginning and the end. If there is only one arrowtip everything is perfect. But with a second mark only the first one is visible. Has anybody an idea what I do wrong?

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,chains,matrix,scopes,fit,decorations.markings,decorations}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}


        \tikzstyle{vecArrow} = [thick,
                decoration={markings, 
                            mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60};}},
                double distance=1.4pt,
                shorten >= 5.5pt,
                preaction = {decorate},
                postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt, white,shorten >= 4.5pt}]

        \tikzstyle{vecArrow2} = [thick,
                    decoration={markings,
                                mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60}},
                                mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[semithick]{open triangle 60};}},
                    double distance=1.4pt,
                    shorten >= 5.5pt, shorten <= 5.5pt,
                    preaction = {decorate},
                    postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt, white,shorten >= 4.5pt}]


        \draw[vecArrow] (0,0) to (1,0);

        \draw[vecArrow2] (0,-1) to (1,-1);


    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The `mark=at position N`s have to be in increasing order.  Try swapping the two declarations and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 8):

Markings have to be specified in the order in which they are to appear on the path: from the manual (Section Libraries -> Decoration Library -> Marking Decorations -> Arbitrary Markings):

> It is possible to give the **mark** option several times, which causes several markings to be applied. In
>   this case, however, it is necessary that the positions on the path are in increasing order. That is,
>   it is not allowed (and will result in chaos) to have a marking that lies earlier on the path to follow
>   a marking that is later on the path.

In your code you have:

```
mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60}},
mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[semithick]{open triangle 60};}},
```

which violates this rule.  Simply swap the lines to:

```
mark=at position 0 with {\arrowreversed[semithick]{open triangle 60};}},
mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60}},
```

and the problem should be solved.